# The y-axis label text is hidden after combining some plots with subplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot

I have the dataset below:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

Then I create 4 heatmaps based on the number of diffrenet `panel` types. As you can see I want the y-axis text to be displayed only for the 1st one and this is why I create it separatedly from the others.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3<-split(Gene_states22[,1:15], Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4<-HG4[,-5]
HG5<-split(HG4, HG4$panel)
p<-list()

p[[1]]<-ggplotly(
  ggplot(HG5[[1]], aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                          colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
    labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
    theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                               size = 14, 
                               face = "bold"), 
          axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                    size = 16, 
                                    face = "bold", 
                                    color = "black"), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                     size = 11),
          axis.text.y= element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                    size = 11),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 10,hjust = 10),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
          strip.placement = "outside")
)%>%
  layout( autosize = F,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                     font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                 size = 9, 
                                                                                 color = "black")))
```

Then I create the rest of them

```
for(i in 2:length(HG5)){


  p[[i]]<-ggplotly(
    ggplot(HG5[[i]], aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                            colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
      labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
      theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 14, 
                                 face = "bold"), 
            axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                      size = 16, 
                                      face = "bold", 
                                      color = "black"), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                     size = 11),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
            panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
            strip.placement = "outside")
  )%>%
    layout( autosize = F,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                       font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                   size = 9, 
                                                                                   color = "black")))
  }
```

And finally I combine them with `subplot`

```
subplot(p)
```

The problem is that I cannot see the y-axis test as you can see in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is removed when you call `subplot`. You can get it back with:

```
subplot(p) %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"))
```

[image]

Comment: yes but how can I take back the gene_symbol which I have in y-axis.not just the title

Comment: If you check at the picture they seem to be there but only the last letter is displayed somehow

Comment: hum...I am not following, the gene symbol is the title for the x-axis. see edit for what I see.

Comment: sorry you re right I meant the samples for the y-axis. I can see now the title" samples" but not the samples

Comment: Also you seem to display only 1 of the 4 heatmaps in the picture.

Comment: sorry...see new image.

Comment: I really cannot understand why it does not work for me even now. The strange thing is that the samples seem to be there from the beginning if you see my picture but its like I have to move the heatmap to the right to display them

Comment: It might be the margins?

Comment: hmm what did you use?

Comment: I actually used your code, but it looks like margins were cut off. I am using the r-studio console with `plotly_4.7.1.9000  ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.

Comment: worked like  subplot(p)%>%layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"),margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10)) soI accept it tnx a lot!